# how to translate a very long mysql query with select and join to zend framework 1.11 model

Tags: mysql, database, zend-framework

I have this mysql query:

```
SELECT 
    freeAnswers.*, 
    (SELECT `districtCode` 
         FROM `geodatas` 
         WHERE `zipCode` = clients.zipCode 
         GROUP BY `zipCode` 
         LIMIT 0, 1) as districtCode, 
    clients.zipCode, 
    clients.gender, 
    clients.startAge, 
    clients.endAge, 
    clients.mail, 
    clients.facebook, 
    surveys.customerId, 
    surveys.activityId, 
    surveys.name as surveyName, 
    customers.companyName, 
    activities.name as activityName 
    FROM freeAnswers, 
         clients, 
         surveys, 
         customers, 
         activities 
    WHERE freeAnswers.surveyId = surveys.id 
         AND surveys.customerId = customers.id 
         AND activities.id = surveys.activityId 
         AND clients.id = freeAnswers.clientId 
         AND customers.id = 1 
    ORDER BY activityName asc 
    LIMIT 0, 10
```

the query is correct on my mysql server but when I try to use it in Zend Framework 1.11 model
I get this error: Mysqli prepare error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Please, could anyone help me to make it run well?

Best Regards,
Elaidon

Comment: Please backtick your query; it's impossible to read. I tried to edit your post and add them in but an edit that short isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that should work.  `Zend_Db_Select` doesn't really provide a way to select from multiple tables in the `FROM` clause without using a `JOIN` so this feels a bit hackish to me in regards to one small part of the query.  Your best bet will probably be to rewrite the query using `JOIN`s where appropriate.

```
    $subselect = $db->select()
                    ->from('geodatas', 'districtCode')
                    ->where('zipCode = clients.zipCode')
                    ->group('zipCode')
                    ->limit(1, 0);

    $from   = $db->quoteIdentifier('freeAnswers') . ', ' .
              $db->quoteIdentifier('clients')     . ', ' .
              $db->quoteIdentifier('surveys')     . ', ' .
              $db->quoteIdentifier('customers')   . ', ' .
              $db->quoteIdentifier('activities');

    $select = $db->select()
                 ->from(array('activities' => new Zend_Db_Expr($from)),
                        array('freeanswers.*',
                              'districtCode' =>
                                  new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $subselect . ')'),
                              'clients.zipCode', 'clients.gender', 'clients.startAge',
                              'clients.endAge', 'clients.mail', 'clients.facebook',
                              'clients.customerId', 'clients.activityId',
                              'surveyName' => 'surveys.name', 'customers.companyName',
                              'activityName' => 'activities.name'))
                 ->where('freeAnswers.surveyId = surveys.id')
                 ->where('surveys.customerId = customers.id')
                 ->where('activities.id = surveys.activityId')
                 ->where('clients.id = freeAnswers.clientId')
                 ->where('customers.id = ?', 1)
                 ->order('activityName ASC')
                 ->limit(10, 0);
```

The only reason I say it is hackish is because of the line:

```
->from(array('activities' => new Zend_Db_Expr($from)),
```

Since `from()` really only works with one table, I create a `Zend_Db_Expr` and specify the correlation as the last table name in the expression.  If you don't pass a `Zend_Db_Expr`, it will either quote your comma separated table name incorrectly, or if you pass an array of table names, it just uses the first.  When you pass a `Zend_Db_Expr` with no name, it defaults to use `AS t` which also doesn't work in your case.  That is why I put it as is.

That returns the exact SQL you provided except for the last thing mentioned.  Here is actually what it returns:

```
SELECT
`freeanswers`.*,
(SELECT `geodatas`.`districtCode`
    FROM `geodatas`
    WHERE (zipCode = clients.zipCode)
    GROUP BY `zipCode`
    LIMIT 1) AS `districtCode`,
`clients`.`zipCode`,
`clients`.`gender`,
`clients`.`startAge`,
`clients`.`endAge`,
`clients`.`mail`,
`clients`.`facebook`,
`clients`.`customerId`,
`clients`.`activityId`,
`surveys`.`name` AS `surveyName`,
`customers`.`companyName`,
`activities`.`name` AS `activityName`
FROM `freeAnswers`,
     `clients`,
     `surveys`,
     `customers`,
     `activities` AS `activities`
WHERE (freeAnswers.surveyId = surveys.id)
AND (surveys.customerId = customers.id)
AND (activities.id = surveys.activityId)
AND (clients.id = freeAnswers.clientId)
AND (customers.id = 1)
ORDER BY `activityName` ASC
LIMIT 10
```

So that will work but eventually you will want to rewrite it using `JOIN` instead of specifying most of the `WHERE` clauses.

When dealing with subqueries and `Zend_Db_Select`, I find it easy to write each subquery as their own queries before writing the final query, and just insert the subqueries where they need to go and `Zend_Db` handles the rest.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Drew010! First of all thanks for your answer but I have a problem. I am inside a model and I replaced all the $db variable of your example with $this, but the debugger get this error: Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Admin_Model_Suggestions::quoteIdentifier() and I do not know why.

Comment: From inside a model, you will have to get an instance of the `DbTable` object which has a `getAdapter()` method that will return the DB adapter that you can call `quoteIdentifier` from.  If you followed the ZF quickstart method for models and mappers, it would look like `$this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->quoteIdentifier(...);`  It will depend on how your models are set up.